# Convert data to a dictionary for post request

Tags: python

I have to following data for some web scraping which is sent as the 'data' for a post request in python:

```
{"operationName":"item","variables":{},"query":"query item {\n  item(attribute_code: [], sku: \"\", name: \"name_here\") {\n    id\n    sku\n    name\n    price\n    final_price\n    description\n    short_description\n    category_ids\n    reward_points\n    news_from_date\n    news_to_date\n    meta_title\n    meta_keywords\n    meta_description\n    created_at\n    min_sale_qty\n    max_sale_qty\n    special_price\n    url_key\n    is_in_stock\n    special_from_date\n    special_to_date\n    pan_coming_soon\n    pan_offer_start_date\n    pan_offer_end_date\n    isStore\n    pan_show_qty_left_after\n    media_gallery_entries {\n      label\n      media_type\n      types\n      file\n      __typename\n    }\n    type_id\n    timestamp\n    tnc\n    status\n    options {\n      attribute_id\n      attribute_code\n      label\n      position\n      options {\n        label\n        value\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    pan_store_auction_start_price\n    pan_store_auction_end_price\n    pan_store_auction_price_drop\n    isAuction\n    isCrypto\n    is_owner\n    is_bid\n    identifier\n    highest_bid\n    total_bids\n    buy_now_price\n    auction_id\n    is_top_bidder\n    fullname\n    current_user\n    is_placed_bid\n    collection\n    sport\n    athlete\n    pan_show_timer\n    seller_comment\n    current_time\n    is_admin_created_auction\n    is_validating\n    last_bid_time\n    bid_reset_interval\n    panini_fee_msg\n    pan_physical_gift\n    physical_gift_description\n    pan_gift_image_1\n    pan_gift_image_2\n    pan_gift_image_3\n    is_address_specified\n    address_id\n    pan_hide_price\n    web_product_icon\n    type_type\n    is_user_liked\n    is_public_visible\n    allow_offers\n    visibility_type\n    likes_count\n    in_public_auction\n    children {\n      key\n      value {\n        id\n        sku\n        name\n        price\n        final_price\n        description\n        short_description\n        category_ids\n        reward_points\n        news_from_date\n        news_to_date\n        meta_title\n        meta_keywords\n        meta_description\n        min_sale_qty\n        max_sale_qty\n        special_price\n        url_key\n        is_in_stock\n        special_from_date\n        special_to_date\n        pan_offer_start_date\n        pan_offer_end_date\n        pan_show_qty_left_after\n        media_gallery_entries {\n          label\n          media_type\n          types\n          file\n          __typename\n        }\n        type_id\n        pan_store_auction_start_price\n        pan_store_auction_end_price\n        pan_store_auction_price_drop\n        pan_coming_soon\n        isAuction\n        isCrypto\n        image\n        pan_hide_price\n        is_user_liked\n        is_public_visible\n        allow_offers\n        visibility_type\n        likes_count\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"}
```

I am currently using this data in source form and I am using `.replace('name_here', name)` at the end to scrape different pages.

However, I think it would be much better if this was in dictionary/JSON format mainly as it is much better to read. Due to the really weird format of this, I can't work out how to convert it to a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use literal_eval from ast.

Like this:

```
import ast
d = ast.literal_eval(<<json_here>>)
```

Get more info here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

But If you get this json from file, you can use:

```
import json 
d = json.loads(<<name_file>>)
```

Comment: thanks, it looks like it should work but if I submit the data in the format of `d` I get a 403 Forbidden response so I assume it's not formatted correctly

Comment: @PythonIsBae did you replace the name of parameter and after do the post request? Do you can print the sending data?

Comment: I ran the code above in another script and copied the output of print(d) into my current script.